# error C2143. Why VC++ don't find my class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working in a project with several classes. All header files are into "include" folder, and all src files in another folder. But at this point, a class that has been working without problems is missing.

The code that produce the error is:

```
namespace render{   
    class CSprite2D
    {   
        CTexture * m_texture;
```

And the error is **syntax error : missing ';' before '*'**
So I don't have any idea about why VC++ don't find my class. The order in wich VC++ compile classes is very estrange: detects error in sprite2D before to try to compile Texture.cpp. Also, CTexture class has been into the project, and running perfectly before the creation of sprite2D.

Could you help me with some trick to find error?

**Edit:**It works, and the solution is to simply forward declaring the texture class (thanks to James and peenut). But now my doubt is: if I've included the texture, why do I need to forward declare texture class? It is not enough to include the header file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order shouldn't matter, are you including the header file prior to that code?

Comment: Have you `#include`-ed the correct headers everywhere you need them?  Do you have a problem with headers recursively including each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just declare it, you use only pointer:

```
namespace render{
    class CTexture; //forward declaration  
    class CSprite2D
    {   
        CTexture * m_texture;
```

Of course, as comments suggets:

- don't forget to include all necessary headers in your *.cpp files
- use forward declarations to break-up circular dependencies (e.g. class A { B * b; }; class B { A * a; })

**Edit**: Asker's edit:

> I've included the texture, why do I need to forward declare texture class?

Imagine you have "sprite.hpp", "texture.hpp", and CSprite2D contains pointer to texture. Without forward declaration you have to include "texture.hpp" always before including "sprite.hpp". Even worse, if your CTexture uses pointer to CSprite2D, you have no other choice but to use forward declaration to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If the header file that code is located in doesn't include anything that eventually contains a definition for CTexture, it won't know what a CTexture is even if other places do.

However, since you are only using a pointer here, you could probably just do a forward declaration and include the header in the .cpp file where the methods / data of CTexture are used to avoid cyclical header includes.